# File Path with spaces in process writeline

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd, terminal, nunit

i wanted to ask a question related to passing a file path with spaces in the cmd... i have this statement that i want to execute

> nunit3-console.exe "E:/folder 1/folder2"

i want to know how can i put double quotes to the file path as folder 1 has white space in between.. i'm using now

```
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine("nunit3-console.exe E:/folder1/Report_Testing.dll");
```

this works if the folder doesn't have spaces.. what is the solution to execute the above command with " " .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a backslash before a double quote then a double quote will be included in the string.

i.e.:

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("nunit3-console.exe \"E:/folder1/Report_Testing.dll\"");
```

Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx for more information.

Comment: what if report_testing is a variable ??

Comment: If you had the filename in a variable called fileName, the code could be for example:
    string fileName = "Report_Testing";
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(String.Format("nunit3-console.exe \"E:/folder1/{0}.dll\"", fileName));